# animating mayavi with moviepy

Tags: python, canopy, mayavi, moviepy

I am trying to figure out how to export 3D plots created with Mayavi to a movie that I can use for presentations in Powerpoint etc. I found a discussion of doing this using moviepy at

http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/11/29/data-animations-with-python-and-moviepy/

I used this code, with slight modifications as follows

```
duration = 6
def make_frame(t):
    u = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360)                                              
    y = np.sin(3*u)*(0.2+0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*t/duration))
    pore_surface.mlab_source.set(y = y)                                         
    mlab.view(azimuth= 360*t/duration, distance=200)  
.
.
.
verts, faces = marching_cubes(large_region, 0.5, (1., 1., 1.))
surface_area = mesh_surface_area(verts, faces)
pore_surface = mlab.triangular_mesh([vert[0] for vert in verts],[vert[1] for vert in verts],[vert[2] for vert in verts],faces) 
mlab.show(pore_surface)

animation = mpy.VideoClip(make_frame, duration=duration).resize(0.5)
animation.write_videofile("pore_surface.mp4", fps=20)
animation.write_gif("pore_surface.gif", fps=20)
```

where marching_cubes is from scikits image

However, I get a broadcast error doing this as follows
(there are 360 values in each of the new values)

Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object: , trait: y, old value: [  0.    0.    1.  ...,  62.5  63.   63. ], new value: [  0.00000000e+00   3.67371235e-02   7.33729915e-02   1.09806628e-01
   1.45937613e-01   1.81666362e-01   2.16894399e-01   2.51524628e-01
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits/trait_notifiers.py", line 340, in **call**
    self.handler( *args )
  File "/Users/iz9/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/sources.py", line 835, in _y_changed
    self.points[:, 1] = y.ravel()
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (360) into shape (43505)
ERROR:traits:Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object: , trait: y, old value: [  0.    0.    1.  ...,  62.5  63.   63. ], new value: [  0.00000000e+00   3.67371235e-02   7.33729915e-02   1.09806628e-01
   1.45937613e-01   1.81666362e-01   2.16894399e-01   2.51524628e-01
.
.
.
this repeats many times. Meanwhile the Mayavi scene does show, and it does show the image spinning while this error continues

I am running Python under Enthought Canopy on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it seems that Mayavi has a problem generating the scene, maybe a problem with your mesh surface, triangular mesh etc.

Have you tried generating the scene with the different parameters, without MoviePy, to see if it works ?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what moviepy is doing, I have never used moviepy.

I suspect it is probably conceptually similar to a method I am familiar with.

There are two ways I know of that create different sorts of movies with mayavi. Both of them use external tools like ffmpeg.

1. Save lots of frames using e.g. `mlab.savefig` and then concatenate them together with a tool such as ffmpeg. (I suspect moviepy is doing this)
2. Set up an animation in mayavi using e.g. `@mlab.animate` and capture the screen output using a tool such as `ffmpeg -i x11grab`.

I have had success with both of these methods. For some (dense) sample code using method #1, see [pysurfer](https://github.com/nipy/PySurfer/blob/master/surfer/viz.py#L2179%20). For some sample code for method two, see [cvu](https://github.com/aestrivex/cvu/blob/master/cvu/dataview.py#L629).